# How to detect end of socket packet in Swift

Tags: swift, sockets

I am building an HTTP server in Swift. The server will eventually run on Linux, but right now only compiles on Mac OS.

Anyways, I have the socket connections working perfectly and I'm able to receive the data stream, but I am having difficulty finding the best way to determine how to detect the end of the socket data stream.

I know there's many ways todo this, and I know that sockets basically just spit out pure binary data and have no concept of a "packet" that has a beginning and end. My question what are the best techniques used to detect the end of a packet sent from a web browser requesting a web page? I know for JSON it's pretty easy, but I'm curious about when the client is requesting a web page specifically.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with sockets. It's defined in the HTTP protocol. You need to study RFC 2616 and successors, specifically that parts about content and chunked encoding.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, and I have reviewed the HTTP protocol. My question was simply what's the best technique used out there. I understand the basics such as the header is key value based separated by a colon, and that two new lines conclude the header. My question is simply what's the best approach when handling this.

Answer (score 1):

InputStream did that for you, you don't have to care about that.

Try to use this:

```
import Foundation

typealias OnComing = (String) -> (Void)

class SocketClient: NSObject, StreamDelegate {

    var host:String?
    var port:Int?
    var inputStream: InputStream?
    var outputStream: OutputStream?

    var status = false;
    var output = ""
    var bufferSize = 1024;

    var onComing:OnComing!

    func makeCFStreamConnection(host: String, port: Int, onComing:@escaping OnComing) {

        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.onComing = onComing

        Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: host, port: port, inputStream: &self.inputStream, outputStream: &self.outputStream)

        if self.inputStream != nil && self.outputStream != nil {

            self.inputStream!.delegate = self
            self.outputStream!.delegate = self

            self.inputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            self.outputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

            self.inputStream!.open()
            self.outputStream!.open()

        }


    }

    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        if aStream === self.inputStream {
            switch eventCode {
            case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
                break
            case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
                break
            case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
                break
                read()
            default:
                break
            }
        } else if aStream === self.outputStream {
            switch eventCode {
            case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
                break
            case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
                break
            case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func read() {
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
        while (self.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable) {
            let bytesRead: Int = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            if bytesRead >= 0 {
                output += NSString(bytes: UnsafePointer(buffer), length: bytesRead, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)! as String
            } else {
                print("# Stream read() error")
            }
        }
        self.onComing(output)
    }

    func write(message:String) {
        let encodedDataArray = [UInt8]("\(message)\n".utf8)
        self.outputStream?.write(encodedDataArray, maxLength: encodedDataArray.count)
    }
}
```

Your problem is resolved by read()

Comment: Would this work outside of the iOS or macOS SDKs? This project was a swift server not an application. From my understanding the Foundation library for plain jain Swift apps is very limited and does not yet include any implementation for this. Also, this post a pre-Swift 3.0 so maybe they added it to the spec since then.

Comment: No, it is for an application

Comment: Then unfortunately your answer is not applicable because in my message above I state this is for a Swift server and not an application.

Comment: uhm! maybe I misunderstood